# How to center a image inside h1 tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image inside an h1 tag and I'm missing something and don't know what it is

https://jsfiddle.net/jbzt38Le/5/ you can find a demo right over here but I will explain anyways

inside my html I have a div like this

```
        <div>
            <h1>
                <span>Load clients:</span> <br/>
                <span><img src="https://i.ibb.co/tMb04W4/ok.png" alt="logo"></span>
                <span>Step 2: Ok </span>
            </h1>
        </div>
```

and over the css i manage to arrange the image size like this

```
        div > h1 > span > img {
            max-width: 10%;
            height: auto;
        }
```

But now, the image (or text) is not centered with the other.
sadly I can't use flexbox because it's and email template and not all the providers are supporting flex at the moment :(
What am I missing?

Comment: If I'm understanding your intent correctly you could just do `h1 {display: flex;text-align: center;}` since `display:flex` will display the children as a row by default, then `text-align` will center your image. However it's generally not good semantics to use a header tag as a parent to images. Oh and your `<br>` tag appears intentional, which will of course interact in ways also. Maybe an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: You mean vertical or horizontal center? Check flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image as background image and then center it with: `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
div > h1 > span > img {
  max-width: 10%;
  height: auto;  
}
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.ci {
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/tMb04W4/ok.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  display:block;  
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
     <span>Load clients:</span> <br/>
     <span class="ci"></span>
     <span>Step 2: Ok </span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add `text-align:center` to the h1 like that:

```
div > h1 > span > img {
        max-width: 10%;
        height: auto;
  
    }
h1 {
  text-align:center;
}
```